# Keyerror on dataframe scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to print a scatterplot of latitude and longitude values from a df. When running this:

```
info.plot.scatter(x=info['latitude'], y=info['longitude'])
```

I get the following key error

```
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([        34.6951242,         34.6951242,         34.6951242,\n                      34.6951242,         35.6580681,         35.6580681,\n                      35.6580681,         35.6580681,         35.6580681,\n                      35.6580681,\n              ...\n                      35.7511648,         35.7511648,         35.6940027,\n                      35.6940027,         35.6617773,         35.6617773,\n                      35.6617773,         35.6617773, 43.055460100000005,\n              43.055460100000005],\n             dtype='float64', length=829)] are in the [columns]"
```

The df looks to be correct when I print the tail. Can anyone figure out whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Forgo the `info` inside `scatter`:

```
info.plot.scatter(x='latitude', y='longitude')
```

Or use `plt.scatter`:

```
plt.scatter(x=info['latitude'], y=info['longitude'])
```